# Populate provinces for selected country on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Contacts are created dynamically (added or deleted). For each contact created, a country must be selected and the provinces for that country must be loaded via ajax.

```
Parent element
#contacts

Child elements
#contacts_0_country 
#contacts_0_provinces

#contacts_1_country
#contacts_1_provinces
etc
```

Everything works perfectly except that i have to switch the country selection twice for the ajax to take charge and change the provinces for the country selected

This problem is due to below js but i cant find it:

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    'use strict';

      $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#contacts').on("change", [$('select')],function() {
    $("select[id^='contacts'][id$='_country']").each(function() {
    var id = parseInt(this.id.match(/\d+/), 10);
    var $country = $("#contacts_" + id + "_country");
    var $province = $("#contacts_" + id + "_provinces");
    
    // When country gets selected ...
    $country.on('change',["#contacts_" + id + "_country"], function () {
      // ... retrieve the corresponding form
      var $form = $(this).closest('form');
      // Simulate form data, but only include the selected value
      var data = {};
      data[$country.attr('name')] = $country.val();
      
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path
        $.ajax({
          url : $form.attr('action'),
          type: $form.attr('method'),
          data : data,
          success: function(html) {
            // Replace current province field ...
            $("#contacts_" + id + "_provinces").replaceWith(
            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response
            $(html).find("#contacts_" + id + "_provinces")
            );
            // Province field now displays the appropriate provinces
          }
        });
    });
    });
    });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question. Below is now working perfectly. Provinces are populated for the relevant country selected and this also works on new contacts added dynamically on the collection

```js
(function ( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    
  $(window).load(function() {
            
    $('#contacts').on("click", [$('select')], function(event) {
    var $id = event.target.id;
    var id = parseInt($id.match(/\d+/), 10);
    var $country = ('#' + $id);
    var $country = $($country);
    
      var $form = $country.closest('form');
          // Simulate form data, but only include the selected value
      var data = {};
      data[$country.attr('name')] = $country.val();
      
        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path
        $.ajax({
          url : $form.attr('action'),
          type: $form.attr('method'),
          data : data,
          success: function(html) {
            // Replace current province field ...
            $("#contacts" + id + "_provinces").replaceWith(
            // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response
            $(html).find("#contacts" + id + "_provinces")
            );
            // Province field now displays the appropriate provinces
          }
        });
    //});

    });
  });
})( jQuery );
```

I hope it helps someone!